# Bloquear letras e caracteres especiais

Tags: c

Boa tarde.
Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C e tenho que tratar quando o usuário digita letras ou caracteres especiais.
Acontece que quando testo digitando uma letra, o programa entrar em loop, tipo piscando na tela.
Queria saber qual como trato isso.
Obrigado

```
int main(){
int opcao_menu;
while(opcao_menu != 5){
printf("\nEscolha sua opção:\n\n\n
        1 - ...\n
        2 - ...\n
        3 - ...\n
         printf...
         printf("\n\n5 - Sair");
         printf("\n\n\nSua escolha: ");
         scanf("%d", &opcao_menu);
system("cls");
            printf("Opcao invalida!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: esse código nem compila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verdade é que, embora a prática tenha mostrado que a função `printf()` é bastante útil para múltiplos propósitos, infelizmente a função `scanf()` não é assim tão útil. Particularmente, ela não lida tão bem com entradas fora do padrão esperado, como você pôde verificar.

Neste caso, a recomendação padrão dos usuários experientes de C é obter a linha inteira para um *buffer* usando `fgets()` (**nunca** `gets()`) e depois analisar a entrada, possivelmente usando `sscanf()` para tal.  Por exemplo:

```
int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    static char buffer[1024];
    int opcao_menu = 0;

    while (opcao_menu != 5) {
        // Literais de string uma após a outra são concatenadas
        // Útil para escrever strings longas
        fputs("\nEscolha sua opção\n\n\n"
              "1 - ...\n"
              "2 - ...\n"
              "3 - ...\n"
              "4 - ...\n"
              "5 - Sair\n"
              "\n\nSua escolha: ", stdout);
        // Obtém a linha que o usuário digitou até o [Enter]
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        // Tenta extrair um número do buffer e verifica os limites do número
        if ((sscanf(buffer, "%d", &opcao_menu) < 1) ||
            (opcao_menu < 1) ||
            (opcao_menu > 5)) {
            system("cls");
            fputs("Opção inválida!\n", stdout);
        } else switch (opcao_menu) {
            // Aqui tratamos os diferentes casos,
            // tipicamente chamando uma função para fazê-lo
            case 1: do_1(); break;
            case 2: do_2(); break;
            case 3: do_3(); break;
            case 4: do_4(); break;
            case 5: fputs("Até mais!\n", stdout); break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, a falta de atenção é uma droga -- `fgets` tem que ler de `stdin`, não de `stdout`.  Quanto à complexidade da solução, bem vindo ao mundo de C.  Com o tempo, você aprende a empacotar as tarefas comuns em funções de biblioteca que você reusa, ou melhor ainda, reutiliza uma biblioteca escrita por terceiros, como [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)...

Comment: Alterei o exemplo, compilando e efetuando alguns testes antes (para isso, precisei criar pequenas funções para tratar as opções 1 a 4 acima, mas isso está além do escopo da pergunta). Se você tentar copiar o código mais uma vez, deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Tente validar se o tamanho da entrada excede o permitido que é 1 dígito, pegando o tamanho com uma função, ou se a primeira pos da não for um dígito.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int tam(char *s) {
    int cont = 0;
    while(*s++) {
        ++cont;
    }
    return cont;
}

int main()
{

    char opc[1024];

    do {

        printf("\nEscolha uma opcao\n");
        printf("0: Sair\n");
        printf("1: Exibir msg 1\n");
        printf("2: Exibir msg 2\n");
        printf("Opcao: ");
        fgets(opc, sizeof(opc), stdin);
        opc[tam(opc) - 1] = 0;
        if(!isdigit(opc[0]) || tam(opc) > 1) {
            printf("Entre com um digito entre 0 e 2\n");
        }

        else {
        int numero = atoi(opc);
        switch(numero) {
            case 0: exit(0);
            case 1:
                puts("Ola");
                break;
            case 2:
                puts("Oi");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao Invalido\n");
                break;
        }
      }
    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```